# PypeR fails if R using library(tm)

Tags: python, r, python-3.5, pyper

I am using PypeR in my Python Application and want to get a variable from a R script.

My Python Application is as follows:

```
from pyper import *
r = R()
r.run("source('<PATH>/test.R')")
words = r.get("words", "No Variable found!", use_dict=False)
print (words)
```

The test.R is just like:

```
setwd("<PATH>")
words <- "Testword"
library(wordcloud)
```

If I run the application without including a library in test.R I get the response "Testword". Why if I include a library (doesn't matter which one), no variable "words" is found? I always get the fallback "No variable found".

I am using Python 3.5 and R 3.2.2 on my Windows 10 machine.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't matter if I use library tm or wordcloud....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: necessary to load dependent librarys first (R does this automatically, PypeR not). Ex.:

```
library(NLP)
library(tm)

library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
```